# Calculating average salary within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the average salary within a dictionary. I understand how to get the average but I am having trouble with just grabbing the info out of the dictionary list and writing it that way rather than a hard code.

```
directory = [{'firstName':"bob",'department':"Accounting",'salary':50000},{'firstName':"alice",'department':"Marketing",'salary':100000}]
```

Need average salaries of the two employees in the directory and save as avgSalary variable as an int

```
avgSalary =
```

I understand that this gives me the correct answer but is there a way to grab it out of dict list rather than hard coding it?

```
def Average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)
  
lst = [50000, 100000,]

average = Average(lst)

print("Average of the list =",round(average))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) for this.

`res = [ d['salary'] for d in directory ]`